# How do I  accept inbound connections for a specific program?

Tags: firewall, ufw

Windows firewall allows to specify a program that will accept inbound connections no matter on which port(s) is listening (instead of specifying the port(s) to allow for that program). Is this possible in Ubuntu with the default firewall? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [this help.ubuntu.com post](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/firewall.html) on the firewall, particularly the "ufw Application Integration" section.

Comment: Unfortunately it is only a mapping between applications and usual port number used by them. If another application use the same port (not at the same time, obviously) the firewall cannot detect. There is no easy way to have firewall rules based on which applications use a given port.

Comment: It looks like the default firewall doesn't really supports applications (if an application uses dynamic ports than this won't be of any help). Thanks.